# Extracting metadata from torrents with Java

Tags: java, bittorrent

Is there any way to extract metadata from a torrent file using Java?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this](http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/org.eclipse.ecf.docs/api/org/eclipse/ecf/protocol/bittorrent/TorrentFile.html).
And [Java Bittorrent API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitext/).