# Parsing a torrent file

Tags: file, scala, encoding

I'm trying to read in a .torrent file with the following code:

```
val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filename, "utf-8")
val lines = source.mkString
source.close()
```

But when I run my program I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

I have tried putting no charset and get the same issue.

What is the problem and what should the charset be for reading a .torrent file?

Answer (score 2):

Torrent file **is not plain text** file, but rather has [binary structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file#File_structure). [Use appropriate library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437420/extracting-metadata-from-torrents-with-java) to decode them

Comment: Hi, I understand the encoding, I have written my own bencoding library - what I don't know how to do is read the raw file data.

Comment: @cm22 benconding is mostly text, but not entirely text. In particular, strings are actually binary strings, i.e. array of arbitrary bytes. So, don't try to read that file as text, read it byte by byte.